# Split vector, categorized by regex

Tags: r

I am searching for a method to split a character vector based on a RegEx pattern.

Example of input:

```
input <- c("a_foo","b_foo", "c_bar", "d_bar")
split_by <- c("foo", "bar")
```

The result I am searching for:

```
$foo
[1] "a_foo" "b_foo"

$bar
[1] "c_bar" "d_bar"
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on the comments and answers, there is need for a clarification.

1. `split_by` can have any number of elements;
2. the RegEx pattern varies from case to case; and
3. an element in `input` may be assigned to 0 (no matches), 1, or multiple splits depending on the match.

Hence, the following input:

```
input <- c("foo_bar", "nothing", "a_foo", "c_bar")
split_by <- c("foo", "bar")
```

Could return:

```
$foo
[1] "foo_bar" "a_foo"  

$bar
[1] "foo_bar" "c_bar"
```

Comment: Can `split_by` have more than 2 elements?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split.regex <- function(input, split_by, pattern, add_names=TRUE) {
  out <- lapply(split_by, function(x) {
    input[grepl(sprintf(pattern, x), input)]
  })
  
  if (add_names) {
    names(out) <- split_by
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

First, the pattern must be defined. Since `foo` and `bar` occurs at the end of the string, `sprintf("%s$", split_by)` can be used. In the function, I defined the `sprintf` inside the function so the argument `pattern` should be defined as the `sprintf` string `"%s$"`.

**First example**

By defining `input` and `split_by` as in the question's first example, and then running:

```
split.regex(input=input, split_by=split_by, pattern="%s$", add_names=TRUE)
```

We get the desired result:

```
$foo
[1] "a_foo" "b_foo"

$bar
[1] "c_bar" "d_bar"
```

**Second example**

By defining `input` and `split_by` as in the question's second example, and then running:

```
split.regex(input=input, split_by=split_by, pattern="(%s)", add_names=TRUE)
```

We get the desired result:

```
$foo
[1] "foo_bar" "a_foo"  

$bar
[1] "foo_bar" "c_bar"
```

Since the input `"nothing"` didn't match on any, it was correctly excluded from the split, whereas `"foo_bar"` was correctly added to both splits as it matched on both.

Answer (score 1):

In real case, can you extract `split_by` values from `input` data?

This works for the example shared.

```
split(input, sub('.*_', '', input))

#$bar
#[1] "c_bar" "d_bar"

#$foo
#[1] "a_foo" "b_foo"
```

where

```
sub('.*_', '', input) #returns
#[1] "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(split_by, grep, x = input, value = TRUE)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a_foo" "b_foo"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c_bar" "d_bar"
```

To get named output you could do:

```
lapply(setNames(split_by, split_by), grep, x = input, value = TRUE)
```